# Reputation sync across sites

Tags: support, reputation

Does reputation you earn on one site (e.g. Area 51) sync to all of the other sites (e.g. Server Fault)?

Comment: Sync? As in, is your reputation global? Then no. It's per site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Reputation earned on one site is separate from reputation earned from another, with a few exceptions:

- Except for Meta Stack Exchange, your reputation on a Meta site is the same as your reputation on the parent site.
- If you have 200 or more reputation on any site, you will automatically get a 100 reputation association bonus when you first log in to a new site.

You can find more information about reputation [in the Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). The Help Center [also has information on Metas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta).